# Pythonic way to write conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm wondering what are the rules to write conditions in Python.
I'm quite new to Python. I come from C and I'm used to set brackets around conditions, which doesn't seem to be the rule in Python.

I was trying to set a condition on a while loop and I encountered a problem, here is my initial code:

```
valid_rx = False
retry = 0

while valid_rx is False & retry < 5:
    # the rest of the code is not particularly relevant, if a failure occurs, I relaunch my attempt and increment retry
```

And it never executed the rest of the code.

I thought my condition was never True, so I tried several combinations and putting brackets around `valid_rx is False` or around `retry < 5` worked properly.
I wanted to know why the initial condition failed, so in a terminal I tried the combinations, and I also tried the following:

```
In [48]: False & retry
Out[48]: 0
```

Does that mean that in my initial condition this part of the condition was interpreted first ?
How does Python processes such a condition ? from left to right ?
does it interprete `valid_rx is False`, then `False & retry`, then `retry < 5` ? 
Actually I would have expected that an asserted condition would be discarded for further evaluation (ie. evaluation of `valid_rx is False` would have prevented `False & retry` from being interpreted) which would have made my initial condition correct ...

If someone has a clear explanation (or reference) I would be interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is not considered as *AND* condition in Python. You have to use [`and`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements).

```
valid_rx = False
retry = 0

while valid_rx is False and retry < 5:
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the logical short-circuit operator `and`, not the bitwise operator `&`.

Also note that the boolean `valid_rx` can be used directly in your condition; more concise:

```
while not valid_rx and retry < 5:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> valid_rx = False
>>> retry = 0
>>> not valid_rs and retry < 5
```

use `not`, `and`. Python is said to be "runnable pseudocode".